# Trying to get the property of non-object in yii

Tags: mysql, yii

Firstly i wanna create query for join in yii..

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('u.mobile,p.mobile')
        ->from('profile p')
        ->join('users u','p.name=u.username')

        ->queryAll();
```

and i wanna show the retrieved data in view as

```
foreach ($data as $show){
echo $show->mobile;}
```

but data is not displaying and shows error as Trying to get property of non-object ..

please help any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method queryAll() will return a set of rows. each row is an associative array of column names and values. Try access as array.
Example:

```
foreach ($data as $show){
echo $show[Your Key]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much..you saved my day

Comment: No problem, and are you use Yii1. i suggest use Yii2, fast and simple